# Adding Google Maps to an Android App

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

Me and my group members have been trying to add Google Maps in one of our activities but all attempts failed. We'd like to ask for some help.

We followed the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start).

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.exapp.maptrial01"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<permission
    android:name = "com.exapp.maptrial01.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel = "signature" />

<uses-feature 
    android:glEsVersion = "0x00020000"
    android:required = "true" />

<uses-permission android:name = "com.exapp.maptrial01.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name = "com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value = "intentionally left blank" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.exapp.maptrial01;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

static final LatLng MarqueeMall = new LatLng(15.163350, 120.609495);
private GoogleMap gMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}   

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gMap = arg0;

    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(15.163350, 120.609495);
    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in MQ"));
    gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
  }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: Please explain where exactly its failing, error description etc.

Comment: An alert dialog with the text "Unfortunately, (appname) has stopped" pops up whenever we install and run the app on a real device.

Comment: What is the error you are getting...?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to have the android key which is described in step 4. and replace

```
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="intentionally left blank" />
```

with

```
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

Comment: I really left it like that. i think the API key is supposed to be hidden. But the key in our app is exactly as the one generated in the Google Console.

Comment: Are you using ddms to see what is happening?

Comment: No. Just focused in LogCat. Where in DDMS should I look at?

Comment: LogCat should have the system messages that logcat has....problems connecting with google will appear with invalid key messages if that's your problem, or if you left out libraries such as google play services etc.  Do you at least get the google logo in the corner?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Upon tapping the app to open it, it automatically closes afterwards. I don't know if it's because we're using a lower revision of the Google Play Services library (using 28 but 32 is the latest), or because of the fact that we're doing the project in Eclipse and not Android Studio.